# windows phone 8 download and play audio on background

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm using background file transfer and background audio player.
in the `TransferStatusChanged` event i save the file to the isolated storage then play it with the audio player,

It works fine if the application is active and i want to do the same if the application is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP8.0 it isn't possible as your `TransferStatusChanged` is in your App process which is stopped when you [navigate away from it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory.

You can make it work under *LockScreen* by disabling *IdleDetection* but it won't work when your App is put into dormant/tombstoned state.

You may consider to start playing when you activate the App or put some logic in BAP where you can check for example upon TrackChange if the file was downloaded and then play it.

---

edit
thanks to @Romasz suggestion of use empty track to play while the file complete downloading 
then in TrackChange  i check if the file downloaded and remove it from the download queue -this can be done in the audio background- things work fine now. here is some code

```
 private AudioTrack GetNextTrack(bool isStart = false)
    {





        AudioTrack track = null;
        using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isStart)
            {
                currentSongIndex = -1;
            }
            currentSongIndex++;
            if (currentSongIndex == _ProgressList.Count())
            {

                //currentSongIndex = 0;
                return track;
            }

            if (ISF.FileExists("shared/transfers/" + _ProgressList[currentSongIndex].FileName))
            {
                var request = requests.Where(it => it.Key ==  _ProgressList[currentSongIndex].FileName).FirstOrDefault().Value;
                if (request != null)
                {
                   bool isDone = ProcessTransfer(request, _ProgressList[currentSongIndex].Directory);
                    if(!isDone )
                    {
                        if(request.BytesReceived > LastDownloadedSize)
                        {
                            NumberOfTrialsToLoadNextTrack = 0;
                            LastDownloadedSize = request.BytesReceived;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ++NumberOfTrialsToLoadNextTrack;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ++NumberOfTrialsToLoadNextTrack;
            }

            if (ISF.FileExists(_ProgressList[currentSongIndex].Directory+_ProgressList[currentSongIndex].FileName))
            {
                track = playList[currentSongIndex];
                NumberOfTrialsToLoadNextTrack = 0;
                LastDownloadedSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                 currentSongIndex--;
                 if (NumberOfTrialsToLoadNextTrack < 10)
                 {

                     track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("halfsec.mp3", UriKind.Relative),
                                          "empty",
                                          "empty",
                                          "empty",
                                           null);
                 }


            }

        }

        return track;
    }

    private bool ProcessTransfer(BackgroundTransferRequest transfer, string directory = "")
    {
        bool isDone = false;
        switch (transfer.TransferStatus)
        {
            case TransferStatus.Completed:


                if (transfer.StatusCode == 200 || transfer.StatusCode == 206)
                {

                    RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId);


                    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        string filename = transfer.Tag;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(directory + filename);
                        if (isoStore.FileExists(directory + filename))
                        {
                            isoStore.DeleteFile(directory + filename);
                        }
                        if (isoStore.FileExists(transfer.DownloadLocation.OriginalString))
                        {
                            isoStore.MoveFile(transfer.DownloadLocation.OriginalString, directory + filename);
                        }

                    }
                    isDone = true;

                }
                else
                {

                    RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId);

                    if (transfer.TransferError != null)
                    {

                    }
                }
                break;



        }
        return isDone;
       // NotifyComplete();
    }

    private void RemoveTransferRequest(string transferID)
    {
        // Use Find to retrieve the transfer request with the specified ID.
        BackgroundTransferRequest transferToRemove = BackgroundTransferService.Find(transferID);

        // try to remove the transfer from the background transfer service.
        try
        {
            BackgroundTransferService.Remove(transferToRemove);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }



 protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
    {
        switch (playState)
        {
            case PlayState.TrackEnded:
                player.Track = GetNextTrack();
                break;
            case PlayState.TrackReady:
                player.Play();
                break;
            case PlayState.Shutdown:
                // TODO: Handle the shutdown state here (e.g. save state)
                break;
            case PlayState.Unknown:
                break;
            case PlayState.Stopped:
                break;
            case PlayState.Paused:
                break;
            case PlayState.Playing:
                break;
            case PlayState.BufferingStarted:
                break;
            case PlayState.BufferingStopped:
                break;
            case PlayState.Rewinding:
                break;
            case PlayState.FastForwarding:
                break;
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

this code in the AudioPlayer class, the files added to the download queue in the xaml.cs normally

Comment: thank for your response, is there are any way to prevent the application from stopping?

Comment: @HagerAly No - from obvious reasons, no user would like to have such a situation. You may think of performing some actions in background by using *BackgroundAgents* on WP8.0 and *BackgroundTasks* on WP8.1.

Comment: the background audio player  cannot be called in the background agent
can i make the audio player wait until the download is done? using time dispatcher in the audio player class to check if file exists

Comment: @HagerAly That's right (i've mant other actions) - it's the only way to do anything while your app is not in foreground, thought as you have said with *agent* you [won't be able to control BAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: @HagerAly I don't think so, the waiting would help. As far as I remember, there is a limited time until you BAP method calls `NotifyComplete();` - [2.Each invocation is allowed 30 seconds.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: @HagerAly One maybe not a good idea ;) - use a fake one minute silent mp3, then upon track change check if the file is already downloaded and then switch to it. I've not tried this :)

Comment: if i gave the audio player the url directly, can i cach the stream to be available offline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55065/discussion-between-hager-aly-and-romasz).